# Returning results outside of a range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to make a booking system in .NET. I have a database with a tables called Booking, Room and BookingRoom.

Room contains the room numbers as Room.RoomID.
BookingRoom has only two Columns, RoomID and BookingID.
Booking has several columns but the ones I want to use are columns for CheckInDate and CheckOutDate along with BookingID.

Room -> BookingRoom -> Booking

Here is where I am now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.RoomID
FROM Room r
RIGHT JOIN BookingRoom br ON br.RoomID = r.RoomID
RIGHT JOIN Booking b ON b.BookingID = br.BookingID
RIGHT JOIN Rates ra ON r.RateID = ra.RateID
WHERE (b.CheckInDate < '2015/06/21 00:00:00' OR b.CheckInDate > '2015/06/27 23:59:59.999') AND (b.CheckOutDate < '2015/06/27 00:00:00' OR b.CheckOutDate > '2015/06/21 23:59:59.999');
```

This unfortunately gives me a list of all rooms as while it excludes the rooms in that range, the room number matches another booking where it is outside.

Now I cannot for the life of me figure out if it's possible to return a list of Rooms, excluding the Rooms that match dates within the CheckInDate and CheckOutDate range.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT
    r.RoomID
FROM Room r
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM Booking b
        INNER JOIN BookingRoom br
            ON br.BookingID = b.BookingID
        WHERE
            (b.CheckInDate < '2015/06/21 00:00:00' OR b.CheckInDate > '2015/06/27 23:59:59.999') 
            AND (b.CheckOutDate < '2015/06/27 00:00:00' OR b.CheckOutDate > '2015/06/21 23:59:59.999')
            AND br.RoomID = r.RoomID
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want unbooked rooms for a period of time.  A rather direct way of doing this uses `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM Room r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM BookingRoom br JOIN
                       Booking b
                       ON b.BookingID = br.BookingID
                  WHERE b.CheckInDate < '2015-06-28' AND
                        b.CheckOutDate >= '2015-06-21' 
                 )
```

Note that I changed the date arithmetic so it will find any overlap.